# Angular 2 - Internet explorer version 11 doesnt show my app. Is there something I need to do for it to show?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Angular 2 - Internet explorer version 11 doesnt show my app. Is there something I need to do for it to show?

Currently the app just shows a blank screen like its not loading the app.

I have no console errors.

It works fine on chrome and firefox.

I'm using html5, typescript and angular2.

Any help would appreciated. Thanks.

**This is my code:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.2/es6-sham.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.src.js"></script>  

 <script>
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    defaultJSExtensions: true,  
    typescriptOptions: {
        emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
    },          
    packages: {
        'angular2-google-maps': {
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this issue could help you: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/issues/24.

From this issue:

- `es6-shim.js` must be before `system.js`
- if you want to run your code in a browser that doesn't support ES6 (like IE11) you need es6 polyfill (`es6-shim.js` is one of them)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Hi, I tried adding this: 

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.2/es6-sham.min.js"></script>  but it didnt work